# How to listen to a third party account for stellar transactions from now?

Tags: java-sdk

I used `paymentRequest.stream` to start listen to events for a third party account.

But it gets all events from the beginning if I don't provide a paging token.  As it is a third party account, my client side application doesn't listen to the event all the time, so it doesn't have the latest `pagingToken`. So I will get a lot of events from the past.

Is there a way for me just to start listening to future events for a third party account? Which means I only want to listen on events from the time the client runs, but ignores everything in the past?

Answer (score 2):

Not 100% sure about Java SDK, but JavaScript SDK allows to specify `"now"` as a cursor to be notified of payments happening starting from when this script runs.

**Edit:**

Looks like the method mentioned above doesn't work with Java SDK. The alternative approach requires two calls instead of one, but it was battle-tested and guaranteed to work.

Prepare request builder for transactions, set `limit` to 1 and execute it. Once you get the response, you have a `paging_token` for the first transaction in a list that can be specified as a `cursor` in streaming mode. If the first request returns zero rows, it means that there were no transactions on this account and you can safely omit a `cursor` in a streaming request call.

Comment: Thanks and I did use "now" from your advice.  I found that without "now", the onEvent was called for all transactions.  But with "now", it wasn't called at all.

Comment: Got it to work, according to your method.  So I have to close the first EventSource returned by the stream function for the first time.  Then I start another stream using the pageToken as cursor and it did work as you said.